Azure DevOps: Deploy static web app from script (not task)
Context: Monorepository (Nx) with multiple applications
I have a Azure DevOps pipeline in which I want to deploy a list of applications under certain conditions. Because I need to run some commands from nx, the list of apps is available only at runtime and not when the pipeline is compiled, so I can't use a for loop something like ${{ each app in variables.apps }} that calls a AzureStaticWebApp@0 task.
For this reason I built the following script:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Retrieve secret'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      for app in $apps; do
         # Check if the deployment-config.json exists for the app
         configPath="apps/$app/deployment-configs.json"
         if [ -f "$configPath" ]; then
            appName=$(jq -r '.appName' "$configPath") # Retrieve app name from config file
            deploymentToken=$(az staticwebapp secrets list --name "$appName" --query "properties.apiKey")
            # Deploy app with the deployment token (from dist/apps/$app)
         fi
      done

I notice there is a static web app CLI swa that's separate from the azure CLI, but I think it is supposed to be used locally. How am I supposed to deploy the app from the script

Hi @AndreaCostanzo, Good day. Have you got a chance to check the answer below to install SWA CLI during the pipeline agent job with the command npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli? Hope it may resolve your query in this post. Thx.

Update
Just in case your current pipeline may incur the deployment_token provided was invalid exception, here is my sample Azure CLI script for your reference. Kindly remember to add the -o tsv argument for your az staticwebapp secrets list command, which can remove the double quotation marks from the output $deploymentToken.

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFAutoSub1'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
      swa --version

      appName="xxxMyStaticWebAppxxx"
      # Add -o tsv to output a valid token without double quotation marks
      deploymentToken=$(az staticwebapp secrets list --name "$appName" --query "properties.apiKey" -o tsv)

      # Check if the token is valid -> Comment out to avoid token leakage -> Consider resetting token after deployment
      # echo "deploymentToken for $appName - $deploymentToken"
      
      swa deploy ./src --deployment-token $deploymentToken --env ${{ parameters.target_environment }}


It seemed that your pipeline was running on Microsoft-hosted agents, where SWA CLI was not installed by default.
You can use a script to install SWA CLI before running swa deploy command for deployment.
- script: |
    npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
    swa --version

You may also configure your local machine/VM/VMSS/MDP with the capabilities of Azure CLI and SWA CLI as a self-hosted agent for your pipeline to run on.
